# Sort & Display WooCommerce Product Attributes by Order

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, sort

I'm attempting to display some WooCommerce attributes on a page based on their *menu order* using get_the_terms and cannot get it to work. Originally, I used this code and it worked fine:

```
$product_values = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'my_value_here');
foreach ( $product_values as $product_value ) {
    // do stuff here like echo $product_value->slug
}
```

But when I tried applying a sorting solution (such as [Sorting Attributes order when using get_the_terms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137926/sorting-attributes-order-when-using-get-the-terms/137928)), it does not work. Here's another one I tried that did not work: [get_the_terms in descending alphabetical order](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224029/get-the-terms-in-descending-alphabetical-order)

In the WordPress Admin, I have the ability to drag-and-drop these attributes to re-sort them. How can I then display them on the site in my sorted order?

Also, to give more detail, I'm displaying the Product Variations on the page using the Attributes created in the back-end of WP. So maybe it's the variations that I need to be able to sort.